# position a div to the right of a centered div?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a `<div>` which is in the center of my page, but now I need to add a div which will be to the right of the center box, I am sure you can do this with [css](/questions/tagged/css) but can't think of a solution.

So for example

```
div#container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 396px;
    display:block;
    margin-top: 110px;
}
```

the div I need would be the same as that kinda? But with +396px to clear the div that's already there? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Float the right div to the right. Be sure it is in your html before the `div#container`.

```
div#container {
    margin:100px auto 0;
    width: 396px;
    height:396px;
    margin-top: 110px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
div#right {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#c6c;
}


<div id="right"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Position the `#container` relative, and `#inner` absolutely.

```
div#container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 396px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 110px;
    position: relative;
}

div#inner {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This would work if i minus the right property, is this an okey way to do it or is this bad practise?

Comment: for example:

div#inner {
    position: absolute;
    right: -230px;top:0px;
 background:#EEEEEE;
 width: 200px;
}

Comment: I do not think my solution is good. I mistook your question. I thought you wanted an inner div.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the float css property.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp

e.g.

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left"> Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```